# mysql limit with inner join and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I have the following query:

```
SELECT saturday_combinations.index, v.val AS  `row` , COUNT( * )  AS  `count` 
FROM saturday_combinations  
INNER JOIN (

SELECT ONE AS val
FROM saturday_combinations 
WHERE ONE IS NOT NULL 

UNION 
SELECT TWO AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE TWO IS NOT NULL 

UNION 
SELECT THREE AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE THREE IS NOT NULL 

UNION 
SELECT FOUR AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE FOUR IS NOT NULL 

UNION 
SELECT FIVE AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE FIVE IS NOT NULL


UNION 
SELECT SIX AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE SIX IS NOT NULL 

UNION 
SELECT SEVEN AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE SEVEN IS NOT NULL 

) v  ON v.val = saturday_combinations.ONE
  OR v.val = saturday_combinations.TWO
  OR v.val = saturday_combinations.THREE
  OR v.val = saturday_combinations.FOUR
  OR v.val = saturday_combinations.FIVE
  OR v.val = saturday_combinations.SIX
  OR v.val = saturday_combinations.SEVEN 
  GROUP BY v.val
```

The purpose of the query is to provide a count of the different values contained in the columns ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX and SEVEN in the table saturday_combinations. However I want to put a desc limit 4 so that it only performs the count based on the last 4 rows (last four maximum indexes). But I am not getting it to work with the union. Adding order and limit at the very end only limits from the final select, rather than get the last 4 rows and calculate the distribution on them. Any tips?

The table schema is as follows:

```
index | ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR|FIVE|SIX|SEVEN
 1       1   3   7     10    11  12  13
 2       3   4   5     30    31  22  23
 3       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 4       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 5       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 6       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 7       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 8       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 9       1   2   3      4     5   6   7
 10      1   2   3      4     5   6   7
```

Index is auto-increment and ONE-SEVEN has integer values.

There are about 3000 rows in the table and I want to count occurences for each value based on the last n rows.

```
Ideal result for the last n rows where n = last 3 rows should be
Numbers|Count
   1       3
   2       3
   3       3
   4       3
   5       3
   6       3
   7       3
```

If I increase n to include last 6 rows their count should increase. If I could last 10 rows the count should increase and other numbers should appear with their count.

Here is a link to a sample of the real table. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d035b

Comment: Please show the table schema and small sample data for your table. Why not use a `case statement` and `count (*)`? Just to clarify, you want each union select subquery to be ordered by desc and limited to 4?

Comment: Hi bonCodigo, I have edited the question include more information.

Comment: Forgot to ask, can you also show what is the ideal expected output? (sample based on your sample table data) Please format those with `code tags.`

Comment: I have included sample and ideal result as well.

Comment: please take a look at the updates. +1 for the qestions :)

Comment: It would be wiser to have your table redesigned. No need for 7 columns when it can be done in one. It would save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If answer to my comment is `yes` then, you could try the following. When you need to add `limit, order by` to `union selects` you need to wrap `union queries` with brackets `()`.

- **[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92f11/3)**

Code:

```
(SELECT ONE AS val
FROM saturday_combinations 
WHERE ONE IS NOT NULL 
order by ONE desc limit 4)

UNION 
(SELECT TWO AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE TWO IS NOT NULL 
order by TWO desc limit 4)

UNION 
(SELECT THREE AS val
FROM saturday_combinations
WHERE THREE IS NOT NULL 
order by THREE desc limit 4)
```

If answer to my comment is `no`, then please clarify.

Here is the code based on your sample date:

```
select distinct x.one as uniqunumbers,
count(x.one) as counts
from(
sELECT DISTINCT 'one' 
AS col1, one FROM sat_comb
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'two' 
AS col1, two FROM sat_comb
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'three' 
AS col1, three FROM sat_comb
) as x
group by x.one;

UNIQUNUMBERS    COUNTS
1               1
3               2
4               1
5               1
7               1
```

### EDIT as per OP has clarified and updated the question.

Quoted: *"However I want to limit it so that it first takes the last n rows and then does the count on the values in those n rows. This means, if I have 3 columns with 3000 rows and 35 integers randomly appearing in these 3000 rows it should count how many times each integer appears."*

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/921a9/2)

Query:

```
select x.one as uniqunumbers,
    count(x.one) as counts
    from(
    (sELECT DISTINCT 'one' 
    AS col1, one FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'two' 
    AS col1, two FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'three' 
    AS col1, three FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
      UNION ALL
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'four' 
    AS col1, four FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
      UNION ALL
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'five' 
    AS col1, five FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
      UNION ALL
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'six' 
    AS col1, six FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
      UNION ALL
    (SELECT DISTINCT 'seven' 
    AS col1, seven FROM sat_comb
     order by id desc limit 4)
    ) as x
    group by x.one;
```

Output:

```
UNIQUNUMBERS    COUNTS
2               4
3               3
4               3
5               4
6               4
8               3
9               4
20              3
```

Comment: In your updated query, where I could I add the limit syntax? Even with brackets the query does not produce the correct result.

Comment: I ran your distinct query but did not quite produce what I was expected. It seem to give a totally different count.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti you may notice that both Bluefeet and mine sort of has the same solution! Mine is as simpler as his ;)  BTW `unpivot` is also a function found in `sql server`. But this whole `union` process called `unpivoting`. Anyway **Can you please confirm what data do you want to limit exactly?** Do you want to get the 4 max distinct numbers from each column? As for the results, do you see the `DEMO` which I have attached. Please notice I am only using first 3 columns as a sample.

Comment: The actual query works if I want to do the count for the whole table. Then I will get the correct result.But that is for the whole table. **However I want to limit it so that it first takes the last n rows and then does the count on the values in those n rows.**  This means, if I have 3 columns with 3000 rows and 35 integers randomly appearing in these 3000 rows it should count how many times each integer appears. For the whole table it works fine. But when I want to limit it for n lasts rows it fails

Comment: By the way sqlfiddle is where I got my query initially but I have not managed to get it work correctly with limit ;)

Comment: You marked Bluefeet's answer, so does his do what you are mentioning here? And as per your expected output in the question (at least it was in the question) doesn't look like what you are saying here now...

Comment: Polite request :) could you please update your sample table data (for few more rows) and expected output with effetive to `desc and limit`?

Comment: select value, count(*) Total from
    (
    ( select 'one' col, one value
    from saturday_combinations order by ONE desc limit 4)
    union all
    does not work. Hope you see what I mean..

Comment: Alright, please correct me here. Last N rows = 4. Then you find unique numbers in these 4 rows for each column (7 columns) then you count. Is that right? Please take a look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36377/1). I have done the last n rows (column value desc) with my own sample data. Please confirm.

Comment: I have updated the question with more data and expected result and what I mean by limit last n rows.

Comment: Thanks for that. :) Here [check the 2nd results set please](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2a5e/1)

Comment: I tried but I am not sure I am getting what you are getting. I have include a sample of my table in sql fiddle. Can you run your query there and check? Here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d035b

Comment: This is what I get from you data, please check [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0d61/2) BTW I didn't see any of your queries but the create/insert. FYI: I have used the `limit by 4` as per my original query and your example. Plesae share if all good.

Comment: Strangely it works on the sample table in sqlfiddler but not quit in my complete table. Oh well, I have to play around with it but thanks for the patience and code!

Comment: I have put in the last 30 rows from my original table and ran your squery in sql fiddle. However as you can see from the result it reports a match of value 2 having count 1 but there are no '2' in the last four rows. There is also only one 32 but it reports two of them. Here is the sql fiddler link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867a6/1

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti Please see the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867a6/12) that you provided me. You may remove the first `distinct`

Comment: Now it works!! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867a6/13 Thanks @bonCodigo , had to remove the distinct from the query

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti very glad you got it worked :) `yup` as per the coment it's the outter `distinct`. Then please mark as the answer. So all gets updated and community knows your questions is solved.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti if this answer was helpful to you then you should accept it via the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: @bluefeet OP did accept it after his last comment. Then I notice he *demark* it...sigh :$ then OP got an answer after all ;-)  the 3rd answer...

Comment: @bluefeet, am a  newbie to stackexchange, I thought the checkbox would be at each comment rather than the original answer. But now I checked it.

Comment: @bonCodigo, checked it now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something in your request but based on your desired result, why not just *unpivot* the data and perform the count.

```
select value, count(*) Total
from
(
  select 'one' col, one value
  from saturday_combinations
  union all
  select 'two' col, two value
  from saturday_combinations
  union all
  select 'three' col, three value
  from saturday_combinations
  union all
  select 'four' col, four value
  from saturday_combinations
  union all
  select 'five' col, five value
  from saturday_combinations
  union all
  select 'six' col, six value
  from saturday_combinations
  union all
  select 'seven' col, seven value
  from saturday_combinations
) src
group by value
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2718/3)

The result of your sample is:

```
| VALUE | TOTAL |
-----------------
|     1 |     1 |
|     3 |     2 |
|     4 |     1 |
|     5 |     1 |
|     7 |     1 |
|    10 |     1 |
|    11 |     1 |
|    12 |     1 |
|    13 |     1 |
|    22 |     1 |
|    23 |     1 |
|    30 |     1 |
|    31 |     1 |
```

Edit #1: Based on your update this might be want you what:

```
select value, count(*)
from
(
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'one' col, one value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by one 
    limit 3
  ) one
  union all
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'two' col, two value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by two desc
    limit 3
  ) two
  union all
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'three' col, three value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by three 
    limit 3
  ) three
  union all
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'four' col, four value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by four 
    limit 3
  ) four
  union all
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'five' col, five value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by five 
    limit 3
  ) five
  union all
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'six' col, six value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by six 
    limit 3
  ) six
  union all
  select col, value
  from
  (
    select 'seven' col, seven value
    from saturday_combinations
    order by seven 
    limit 3
  ) seven
) src
group by value
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bede/7)

Result:

```
| VALUE | COUNT(*) |
--------------------
|     1 |        3 |
|     2 |        1 |
|     3 |        4 |
|     4 |        4 |
|     5 |        3 |
|     6 |        3 |
|     7 |        3 |
```

Comment: +1 for the simpler query, but where could I put the desc limit to only count from the last n rows ?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti I am not sure what you want to limit. Can you update your OP with a sample showing what to limit?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to look at the final solution:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/867a6/13
Thanks to @bonCodigo for all the help